# Como dar color a la linia separadora de rows en css grid?

Tags: html5, css3, grid

Hola estoy creando una copia de la pagina principal de búsqueda de Google. Estoy creando el footer con un grid para crear los dos espacios y darles los atributos. Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que la linea que separa los dos rows sea de color blanco y de anchura un px.
Dejo una imagen de como quiero que queda y de como esta quedando.

Como quiero que quede:
[image: Como quiero que quede la linea]

Como me esta quedando sin la linia:
[image: Como me esta quedando sin la linia]

Como veis en mi grid no consigo hacer aparecer esa fina linia que divide los dos rows. Adjunto codigo HTML y CSS a ver si alguien me puede hechar una mano:

Codigo HTML:

```
<footer class="grid">
        <ul class="footer-top">
            <li>
                <a href="">España</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="footer-top2">
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="footer-top3">
            <li>
                <a href=""></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="footer-left">
            <li>
                <a href="">Publicidad</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Empresa</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Cómo funciona la Búsqueda</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="footer-center">
            <li>
                <a haref="">Emisión neutra de carbono desde el 2007</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="footer-right">
            <li>
                <a href="">Privacidad</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Condiciones</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Preferencias</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
```

Codigo CSS:

```
.grid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 36% 33%;
    grid-template-rows: [y0] 50% [y1] 50%;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-top-color:1px solid #f2f2f2;


}


.grid ul{
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

footer .footer-left{
    justify-self: left;

}

footer .footer-center{
    justify-self: center;
    padding-left: 25%;
    margin: 25px;

}

footer .footer-right{
    justify-self: right;
}

footer ul li a{
    margin: 10px;
    color: #5f6368;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadir esto en tu CSS:

```
ul[class*='footer-top'] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}
```

Y para que la línea llegue al borde del lado izquierdo, puedes cambiar el

.grid ul {margin: 10px;}
por
.grid ul {padding: 10px;}

Comment: Y para que la línea llegue al borde del lado izquierdo, puedes cambiar el

.grid ul {margin: 10px;} 
por
.grid ul {padding: 10px;}

Comment: Mil gracias me ha funcionado perfectamente